# Call the official *Settings* app from my app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings, url-scheme

At one point in my app, I would like to redirect the user to the official *Settings* app. If possible, I also want go straight to the *Network* section within the *Settings* app.

I think what I need is the *Settings* app's url scheme and the format to construct my request. But I doubt that calling such an official app is forbidden.

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: There isn't such a URL scheme (for general public).

Comment: There is now in iOS5, see my answer below.

Comment: Can you please link the documentation, what ensures that it is public? Thanks.

Comment: Find a list of known urls of the settings app in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bad news: As @Hlung and @jasongregori suggested, for iDevices whose OS version **>= iOS 5.1 && < iOS 8.0**, there is once again **NO** official/documented way to call the built-in Settings app from a third-party app. Period.

Comment: I'm agree with this and I also can't make this calls to work.. but some apps are still doing this calls (I'm running iOs 6.1), like Twitter and Flipboard when you are in airplane mode... how do they do it?

Comment: @Omer This solution is not working for iOS 10 . I am working on Xcode 8, swift 3. Any alternate solution please?

Answer (score 44):

As noted in the comments below, this is no longer possible in  iOS version 5.1 and after.

If you are on iOS 5.0, the following applies:

This is now possible in iOS 5 using the 'prefs:' url scheme.  It works from a web page or from an app.

example urls:

```
prefs:root=General
prefs:root=General&path=Network
```

sample usage:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]]
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]]
```

Comment: dude, you are awesome! after some poking around i found this one for twitter settings: `prefs:root=TWITTER`

Comment: Any idea if these calls are classified as 'undocumented'?  I couldn't find them in the docs.  How did you find them?  Cheers,

Comment: Is there a way to get into an App's settings menu?, EG prefs:root=Facebook

Comment: @MattyG yes, definitely. in fact, i just read this article that said these no longer work in iOS 5.1: http://www.macstories.net/news/ios-5-1-beta-blocks-shortcuts-to-system-settings/

Comment: Just a kind warning, http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/29/iphone-5-1-disables-shortcuts/ said that all url schemes to iOS settings will be removed in iOS5.1 (so urls like `prefs:root=General&path=Network` will no longer work) So, please aware.

Comment: What would be solution for iOS 7?

Answer (score 34):

From IOS 8 you can call the settings from within app with this:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];`

Comment: The above line is directing to **app private settings**. Is there any way to direct to **privacy** section of the device settings? Please comment if you know. This redirection is possible as I saw it in maps app where it directs to location settings in privacy section.

Answer (score 17):

It's also work in iOS version > 5.1, but you must add an URL schemes in URL types in Xcode:

[image]

Then you can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

It's can open system WiFi setting
 now.

Other path please find in this answer: [iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme?rq=1).

Comment: @MichaelDorner -- This will not be rejected by Apple, correct?

Comment: @Anton -- This will not be rejected by Apple, correct?

Comment: @iOSAppDev unfortunately with release iOS10 this is not working anymore. But previous versions were successfully uploaded on AppStore.

Comment: @Anton Many thanks for the confirmation. I am more than glad that you replied back. Thank You :)

Answer (score 12):

Calling the settings app from other app is possible only from iOS 8. So, use the following code

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]&&
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
  //...Location service is enabled
}
else
{
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]<8.0)
    {
      UIAlertView* curr1=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location service" message:@"You can enable access in Settings->Privacy->Location->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      [curr1 show];
    }
    else
    {
       UIAlertView* curr2=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location service" message:@"You can enable access in Settings->Privacy->Location->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
       curr2.tag=121;
       [curr2 show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (alertView.tag == 121 && buttonIndex == 1)
 {
  //code for opening settings app in iOS 8
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

from iOS 8, you can redirect with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional answer to add onto the one's addressing iOS8+. If you're supporting anything below 8, you should check to see if it's supported

```
BOOL canGoToSettings = (UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
if (canGoToSettings)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For settings in iOS 9 this is worked for me.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Settings"]];
```

But make sure you add a url schemes in URL types in

Info tab in app targets.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10 you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Settings"]];
```

It is also working on iOS 9!