# How to launch iPhone settings app from my app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

How can I launch the iPhone settings app from my own app? For example, like the screen shot I got from twitter app below:
[image]

I turned off the network, and the twitter shows me a network error alert. But in the alert view, they implement a button "Settings". When I　press the button, it brings the iPhone settings app up.

So I am curious on if there any methods can be called to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone

Comment: @edc1591 The topic may be a dupe, but the question is better and specific to the AlertView shown. One of the comments of one of the answers actually gives the solution to reproducing the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. This dialog is provided by Apple when data is not available for an app that has set Wifi as a requirement in its info plist.

Comment: But it seems this is provided by the Twitter application, not Apple.

Comment: It is provided while the Twitter application is running by Apple based on the application's configuration. Similar to iPod music playing in the background while your app is running.

Comment: How would one do that (configure their application to note that an internet connection is needed)?

Comment: Set this info.plist key to YES http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12

Comment: @jin Thanks, if I set "UIRequiresPersistentWiFi" key to YES, if I am using 3G to connect internet, will this alert show?

Comment: @Jing I believe so, but not 100% sure.

Comment: It won't show in that situation, @Jing. In another part of that page, Wi-Fi is referred to as "the networking feature" of the device. When I turn my Wi-Fi off, but have 3G on, the app launches normally. Only with Wi-Fi & 3G off will it display this dialog. I don't know what will happen on EDGE. It will also display the dialog if you switch away from the app, turn off networking, and switch back.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would need to use custom URL schemes to access other Apple apps, but settings is not available and not part of this list.

Example:

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2010/11/08/insecure-handling-url-schemes-apples-ios/