# How can i switch to settings from my app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

I would like to switch my user to settings app if he answered by no for using his localisation. i'm using an alert view to do that

Comment: Be careful, this won't work on iOS5.1

Answer (score -2):

Use this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone) for more details.

Edit: As Reed wrote in the comments, this is not possible in iOS 5.1.

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS 5.1 and beyond.

Comment: Bummer. :( If you know of any other ways to do this, please share it with us.