# Call the official *Settings* app from my app on iPhone(Location Service，IOS 5.1.1)

Tags: iphone, ios, settings

At one point in my app, I would like to redirect the user to the official Settings app. If possible, I also want go straight to the Location service section within the Settings app.

i have seen

[Call the official *Settings* app from my app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone)
but
In iPhone4 the following code does not respond(my ios version 5.1.1):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];//1 call Location service
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];//2 //call wifi
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]];//3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple removed the ability to reach those setting beginning with iOS 5.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, none that I'm aware of. It was super handy, allowing things like one-tap access of Bluetooth settings from your app, as well as location services, as in your example. I can only assume it was being abused in some way. The only option I know of is to clearly explain to the user how to do it himself, which is much less likely to work out.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

This is what you want. It takes the settings bundle and allows you to use in directly in your app.

Comment: No, he wants to have the OS Settings app display its own Location section (likely to allow the user to easily turn on location for his own app). This isn't a question about putting your own app settings in the Settings app.

Comment: Indeed, but since this isn't possible as suggested above, that is a possible compromise.

Comment: I don't see how it would help. You want the user to change a system setting so you add some settings of your own?