# Open bluetooth settings on button tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I've done enough looking up to now that how this used to be possible on iOS 5.1 and below, and that it's not possible in any version above that.

But how do other apps do it?

So far, I've tried the following (tested on **iOS** **8.1** simulator, on **Xcode**):

```
- (void)turnOnBlueToothPressed:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Which opens the app's settings. Not ideal, but it is what it is.

AFAIK, using the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth"]]
```

No longer works. Alternatively, could anyone point me to the **official documentation stating that it no longer works on any version > iOS 5.1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, now you can open only current app settings, sorry .....=(
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html

Answer (score 2):

This works in iOS version **5.1 and above**.

You must add URL schemes `prefs` in *URL types* in Xcode's `info.plist` tab like below:

[image: url types in info.plist tab]

**Objective-C**:

```objective-c
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

**Swift**:

```swift
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root=WIFI")!)
```

This will open WIFI Settings from your application.

Related SO links:

- [iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme?rq=1)
- [Call the official settings app from my app on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Tested on _ios 9_ and it works, but I tried on _ios 11_, `prefs:root=Bluetooth` did not work, `App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth` did open settings, but not Blueetooth. `App-prefs:root=Bluetooth` did work on _ios 11_ so the case seems to be important.  Only needed `prefs` in Url schemes

Comment: @GabLeRoux on iOS 11 do we need to add URL type too... for me non of solutions are working, any Idea?

Comment: I'm upgrading to latest ios version and will try again. But I've found this github project that says ios11 has problems: https://github.com/phynet/iOS-URL-Schemes

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: The following method works for all the versions below iOS 11, for higher versions the app might get rejected since it's a private API**
*This comes under Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements*

Here are the list of all [short url strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024467/563848):

If you want open Bluetooth settings :

**Swift 3 :**

```
let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth")
let app = UIApplication.shared
app.openURL(url!)
```

Use below code to just open settings:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))`

Comment: does not work on iOS 11 only settings page opens instead. Any updates?