# Opening Safari settings with NSURL Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

Is it possible to open Safari app settings using NSURL link ?

Here is the code i'm using for general settings

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

How should i modify it - if its even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this post: [Call the official *Settings* app from my app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone)

From that post follow this two steps:

First go to Info -> URL Types and add URL Schemes as prefs as shown in below image:

[image]

After that use this code for open safari settings:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root=Safari")!)
```

And result will be:

[image]

Comment: sorry, Dharmesh, but this approach leads to the AppStore rejection (

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 16, should be

```
Link("Setting Safari", destination: URL(string: "App-Prefs:Safari")!)
```

And we can even goto the subpages with an `&path=WEB_EXTENSIONS`

```
Link("Setting Safari", destination: URL(string: "App-Prefs:Safari&path=WEB_EXTENSIONS")!)
```

Also if you want goto somewhere else in the settings, it is also possible:

taking Apple ID page as an example:

```
Link("iCloud Account", destination: URL(string: "App-prefs:APPLE_ACCOUNT")!)
```

BTW, on our app, the review passed.

[image]

see [github repo](https://github.com/kasimok/DeepLinkDemoApp) for more examples.